# XAML Serialization object not using asp.net shadow copy

Tags: xaml, serialization, xamlparseexception

I'm having a problem where i use the XAML serializer / deserializer for a configuration type file that i have.  The problem that i'm getting, is that the XAML serializer is returning objects from the assembly in the /Bin directory, while the rest of the web application is using assembly's stored in the ..../Temporary Files/.. directory.

Is there any way to prevent this from happening?  Is this a bug in the XAML serializer / assembly loading routines?

Every time i compile i need to stop and start the asp.net application so the shadow copy and the bin are *exactly* the same file.  Even when not making a change to the dll and recompiling still causes the problem.

Any thoughts on how to get around this problem?

Currently i've tried turning shadow copy off, but then i have the same problem of needing to shut down / start up the web app every time i compile.

Help!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried loading the assembly from the correct directory manually before deserializing (using Assembly.Load...)?

Comment: Yep, that is sorta / somewhat the problem.  The WPF / XAML parser is ignoring the already loaded assembly, and loads it from the /Bin instead of the temporary files location of asp.net.